# Purchase events not showing in GA4 Monetization (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics-4

I have log purchase event as conversion for our android and ios application. I have setup all properties correctly in GA4.

The issue I am facing is when event triggered I can see the event in real-time on GA dashboard but not in E-commerce section of monetization. I know it takes 48 hours to reflect but even after 48 hours I don't see conversions thought for our website I can see connversions but only for app platform it is nnot showing

Also it was working fine previously for apps as well. If someone has any idea please let me knnow.

I tried to debug and check in console logs are triggering. Also try to see in real-time it is working fine.